# Get issues CreatedBy user using Octokit

Tags: github-api, octokit, octokit.net

I am using *Octokit* to make a report and I need to get the issues of a given repository (which is not hard using the `client.Issue.GetAllForRepository` method) but then I need the issues' `CreatedBy`, and `ClosedBy` when it applies, however it seems both fields are always `null`. Is there a way to get those without making a hit for every issue.

**Note:** I'm using *Octokit 0.22.0*

Here is my issue querying code:

```
var issues = await client.Issue.GetAllForRepository(organization, repo, new RepositoryIssueRequest
        {
            State = ItemStateFilter.All,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue), issues don't return a `created_by` field: do you mean to just get the `user` field instead?

As for the missing `closed_by` block, the default state for returning a list of issues is `open`, meaning closed issues won't be returned. I'm wondering if this is why all of your `closed_by` fields are `null`?

Comment: I am getting all issues, both open and closed, and yet I'm not getting the `closed_by` field. As for the `user` field, I'm not entirely sure what's the difference with 'created_by`, I'd really appreciate if you could point it out. Thank you very much

Comment: My understanding is that the `user` field on an issue reflects the user that created the issue—i.e. it is the `created_by` field you're looking for (but that doesn't exist for issues, if the example JSON is anything to go by).

Answer (score 0):

If the `closed_by` field is null, it means the issue is open. The `user` field is equivalent to `created_by`.